# Append double quote to string

Tags: c#, xml

I have a one xml node with name

```
<St:ABC="3">APPLE</St:ABC>
```

I want to pass this node name  to a string variable like

```
string NodeName="St:ABC="3"",
```

But I am facing te double quote error .I tried to replace like this

```
  String myString = "\"" + 3 + "\"";


 String  myString1 = myString.Replace(@"\", String.Empty);

string CompleteChaildNode = "St:ABC"+ "=" + myString1;
```

I am unable to replace the "\" value in the string can someone help on this

I am updating the inner tag value like this

TimeSeries[CompleteChaildNode].InnerText = Orange;

Comment: When you want to include a double quote in a string you have to delimit it with either a backslash or with another double quote if it is a verbatim string `"\"quotes\""` or `@"""quoted"""`.  If you view a string in the debugger it will display it with the double quotes delimited by backslashes, you do not need to remove them.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to replace the \ value in your string. It is used in a string literal to signify that the following character is not meant as a quote, but as a character of the string (called a character escape). The \ itself is not a part of the string. So you can just write...

```
string NodeName="St:ABC=\"3\""
```

...which will be stored as {St:ABC="3"} (without the braces).

Note that if you check your value in the immediate window or in a value popup, you will still see `"St:ABC=\"3\""` as the value. That is because Visual Studio presents the value to you in its escaped form. That does not mean that the value is actually stored like this.

Comment: I need to update the inner tag Of the XML  node when I am processing it shows the same "\" and getting object reference issue

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to remove the slashes. They are just escape characters. If you have:

```
var myString = "St:ABC=\"3\"";
```

It stores it as St:ABC="3". You can test this with a simple print to screen:

```
MessageBox.Show(myString);
```

Comment: I am unable to use that in updating the inner tag .as it shows the same "St:ABC=\"3\"

Comment: Can you add the code you are trying to use to your question? What is the line that gives you the error?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String myString1 = myString.Replace("\"", String.Empty);
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as in the question. Just not with a verbatim string.

Comment: It Replaces the "\"  missing the double quote "St:ABC=3"

Comment: Actually, it's worse, it replaces the quote, which OP wants in his string.